# JS and SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

Tags: javascript

Looking for some help here, I am getting this error from this script:

error:

SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

call_Logs(140213FS01)

script:

```
"aoColumnDefs": [            
                 {
                   "aTargets": [ 3 ], // Column to target
                   "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
                       //alert (JSON.stringify(full));  //************show contents of Object

                     var str = full[2];
                     return '<a href="#;" onclick="call_Logs('+str+')"; >' + data + '</a>';

                   }
                 }
            ]
```

......

```
function call_Logs(id){



    alert("Call Logs Funct :"+id);

}
```

Comment: Make that `call_Logs(\''+str+'\')"`

Comment: Brilliant !!! Thank you! What are the \ for or represent, just for some clarification

Comment: It escapes `'` character. Eventually you have something like this in your html string:  `call_Logs('str_value')`.